# Unable to check if a value exists in an array

Tags: excel, vba

While trying to check whether a value is present in an array `If Not IsError(Application.Match(arrString, RegM, 0)) Then...`

But for some reason it doesn't work.
I also tried the following but without success `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(DirArray2, RegM)`

When I check the values in a msgbox everything seems ok, but still it doesn't work (below msgbox shows for example "DMM | DMM|TEST"

`MsgBox RegM & " | " & Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(DirArray2, RegM)`

I quoted the whole function because perhaps you find something in the code that causes the problem

```
Sub mk_RegExp()
    If Sheets("MISC").Range("C62") = True Then
        Dim objRegex As Object
        Dim RegMC As Object
        Dim RegM As Object
        Dim item As Variant
        Dim DirArray As Variant
        Dim DirArray2 As Variant
        Dim DirArr As Variant
        Dim test As Variant
        '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Sheets("LI").Range("C12:DJ42").Font.Color = vbBlack
        '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        arr = Sheets("MISC").Range("R4:R145").Value
        LastRow = Sheets("MISC").Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
        DirArray = Join(Application.Transpose(Sheets("MISC").Range("L4:L" & LastRow).Value), "|")
        LastRow2 = Sheets("MISC").Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
        DirArray2 = Join(Application.Transpose(Sheets("MISC").Range("M4:M" & LastRow2).Value), "|")
        arrString = Join(Application.Transpose(Sheets("MISC").Range("M4:M" & LastRow2).Value), ",")
        DirArr = DirArray & "|" & DirArray2
        '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        With objRegex
            .Global = True
            .Pattern = DirArr

           For Each item In arr
                If .test(Range(item).Value) Then
                    Set RegMC = .Execute(Range(item).Value)
                    For Each RegM In RegMC
                        If Not IsError(Application.Match(arrString, RegM, 0)) Then
                            'MsgBox RegM & " | " & Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(DirArray2, RegM)
                            Range(item).Characters(RegM.FirstIndex + 1, RegM.Length).Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                        ElseIf RegM = "COL" Or RegM = "CRT" Then
                            Range(item).Characters(RegM.FirstIndex + 1, RegM.Length).Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
                        Else
                            Range(item).Characters(RegM.FirstIndex + 1, RegM.Length).Font.Color = RGB(247, 150, 70)
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next item
        End With
    Else
        Sheets("LI").Range("C12:DJ42").Font.Color = vbBlack
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You are not actually using arrays, you are using arrays joined by vertical bar, i.e. a delimited string.  You need to try `INSTR` for the string comparison

Comment: Thanks Nathan, `INSTR` did the job. I updated it to `If InStr(DirArray2, RegM) Then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to my comment

```
Sub test_array()

Dim a() As Variant

a = Application.Transpose(Range("a1:a5"))

Debug.Print Join(a, "|")

Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Test 2", a, 0)
Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Test 2", Join(a, "|"), 0)


End Sub
```

The second line errors, the first is ok.